# OS X Use NSImageView for NSWindow background

Tags: macos, transparent, nswindow, titlebar, nsimage

I am trying to use an NSImageView as the background for an NSWindow I have it setup and it shows the image just fine I am using the full size content view to have the image take up the whole window. The problem I am having is the title bar with the buttons is being placed over the image and it is a transparent white color.

Is there a way I can make the title bar for a window transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dumb the answer I was looking for is to call

```
[self setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES];
```

Reading documentation works!